# Webview does not prevent opening links in browser

Tags: java, android

I have a very simple test app with a webview component on it. I'm trying to prevent link being opened in browser but "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" look like it's not working for me.

can someone please help me to see where is the error?

```
    package it.quicktest.calculus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("https://paolo9785.com?page=contacts");


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.webView.canGoBack()) {
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    private class webView extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
            if(url.indexOf("paolo9785.com") > -1 ) return false;
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you even registered your custom `WebViewClient` in `onCreate`?

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new webView()); // new class, NOT WebView instance...
```

you should change name of this class... it's VERY confusing...

```
private class webView extends WebViewClient
```

maybe

```
private class PaoloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
```

and then

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new PaoloWebViewClient());
```

Comment: i forgot to register my custom class in onCreate! It works now. Thank you very much!!!